# Chronoforms 6: jQuery.G2 is undefined

Tags: jquery, chronoforms

I have an issue with Chronoforms6. I'm using jQuery in my template and include a Chronoforms form in an article by using this shortcode `{chronoforms6}myForm{/chronoforms6}`.

The issue is a this error from Chronoforms ***jQuery.G2 is undefined***.

If I deactivate my included jQuery script, Chronoforms works perfect, but my functions won't run anymore, cause for them jQuery is know undefined. 
I believe this is cause my scripts from the template are loaded before the jQuery from Chronoforms, but who can I change this? Or how do I do this better?

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution for me by starting every script that uses jQuery with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //my awesome script });
```

Further I had to change the **$** to **jQuery** in the whole **bootstrap.bundle.js**

After that everything runs without an error, but for me, this doesn't seem to be a clean solution. I would appreciate further advice.

Comment: If that's the case, then something is very wrong. You should not have to modify vendor libraries at all.

Comment: I thought so^^ This isn't something I like to do. But my template is very simple. The used jQuery lib is from Bootstrap. And that is all I've integrated in the template. So could there be some influence form Moduls or Plugins? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i managed to solve it with the plugin jQuery Easy.

Comment: This is a low-quality answer (and it has been flagged in the system as such) because it is an extension recommendation that makes no attempt to explain how or why it is a good idea.  In its current state, this single sentence post would be better dropped onto the page as a comment under the question.  This very well might be a terrific recommendation, I don't know,  but this answer would much more valuable to future researchers if there was more guidance offered.  Remember a good answer begins with a correct/working solution, but great answers educate and empower.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude or bossy.  Striving for higher quality content is what makes this community great and valuable.  Please edit your answer.  Thank you for sharing your knowledge.